# WSO2 APIM error connection to MSSQL database from APIM deployment file

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure a connection to Microsoft SQL server through wso2 API manager. I have added the database connection in the deployment.toml file and added the JDBC driver. I getting the following error when running APIM:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver
> could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure
> Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed:
>
>  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target".
> ClientConnectionId:47e27af8-eb0d-429b-be14-5499b46f69db

I am able to run APIM to get the Urls, but it does not load on the web browser.

below is the database configuration:

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://ip\\test:port;databaseName=WSO2AM_DB;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false"
username = "username"
password = "password"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://ip\\test:port;databaseName=WSO2SHARED_DB;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false"
username = "username"
password = "password"
```

Any help will be much appreciated as I am new to this. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you are missing the MSSQL certificate in the client's trustore. Hence try importing the MSSQL Public certificate to WSO2 trustore. Take a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/configuring-the-client-for-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#configuring-the-client-trust-store) for more details.

```
keytool -import -alias <alias> -keystore  $IS_HOME/repository/resources/security/client-trustore.jks -file mssql.cer
```

Also you can try disabling SSL verification(not recommended) by adding the following properties to the connection URL.

```
encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;
```